# Fluent Wait in selenium with custom condition - chrom

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait, fluentwait

I have an issue that I am facing, I want to create a function that waits until the text "Other" exists in List.
I want it to wait 30 seconds, and in every 5 seconds it will do the call again and validate the new list.
(Maximum 5 - 6 times to validate if the text exists in the new list ).
I have done the validation by converting the List into map and check any match (the map converting and the checking is working).

The problem is with the wait mechanism, I try to create complex fluent wait that will also receive boolean in case of finding the expected text and then the wait should stop. But I do not figure out what to return if it is not found the text for example in the first or second tries, and I want it to still wait and made the call again and validate again.

- I want the wait to stop only in two cases:

  - the word "Other" exists - in this case isExists is true.
  - the the time passes is more than 30 seconds.with pulling interval of 5 seconds and the word "other" not displayed

Is there a way to set in the condition of the wait to wait for Boolean == true ?I am not sure that the condition  Boolean>()  is correct and can be done here in the wait.until , and if it will work

```
public void testrIntegrationfluent ()
{
    WebElement element = BasePage.getWebElementByXPathWithWaitToClicable("//nz-select[@formcontrolname='selectedIntegrationTypes']/div");
    element.click();
    WebDriver driver2 = WebDriverMgr.getDriver();

    Wait wait = new FluentWait(driver2)
            .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

    wait.until(new Function<WebDriver , Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply (WebDriver driver2) {

                List<WebElement> dropdownOptions = driver2.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@class, 'ant-select-dropdown-menu')]/li"));
                Boolean  isExists = dropdownOptions.stream().map(WebElement::getText).anyMatch(text -> "Other".equals(text));
                if (isExists.equals(true)) {
                    return isExists;
                }
        return  ****** need to think what to put thatkeep waiting and perform  call for list and validation reoccured ******
    }

});
}
```

Comment: Is this not working? Your code will wait for 30 seconds  and it will check the boolean value true or not. It should work. Are you getting any error?

Comment: Does return false not work? If you return false, your `wait.until` function should continue waiting.

Comment: is this  Boolean>()    meaning that it wait for the return value will be true?

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your code as such -- using the `FluentWait` you declared. You could replace your entire `wait.until(new Function<WebDriver , Boolean>()` block containing the `apply` function with just this line. Rather than calling the mapping to get text for all the `li` elements and checking for text other, you can write your function to look directly for `li` with text `Other`:

```
fluentWait.until
    (ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElement(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@class, 'ant-select-dropdown-menu')]/li[text()='Other'])));
```

This code will wait until `li` containing text `Other` is present.

Comment: but the xpath is for 30 web elements. Is presenceOfElement will check for all the text, in all this elemets? or just search for the first elemet.

Comment: Using just `presenceOfElement`, the wait will stop once a single element has been located. If you want to wait for all elements located, you can swap out `presenceOfElement` with `presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy` and this will wait for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

After doing your suggestions 
return false solved it